# Extract some keywords like rent, deposit, liabilities etc. from unstructured document

Tags: machine-learning

Writing an algorithm to extract some keywords like rent, deposit, liabilities etc. from rent agreement document. I used "naive bayes classifier" but the output is not giving desired output:
my training data is like:
train = [
("refundable security deposit Rs 50000 numbers equal 5 months","deposit"),
("Lessee pay one month's advance rent Lessor","security"),
("eleven (11) months commencing 1st march 2019","duration"),
("commence 15th feb 2019 valid till 14th jan 2020","startdate")]

The below code is not giving desired keyword:
classifier.classify(test_data_features)

Please share if there are any libraries in NLP to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to make your specific NER(Named Entity Recognizer) for parsing your unstructured document.

where you need to tag every word of your sentence into certain labels. Based on the surrounding words and context window your trained NER will be able to give you the results which you looking for.

Check standford corenlp implementation of NER.

Comment: Thanks for response. I was checking NER and it looks it is often used to extract information about person, location, organisation etc. I am not sure if it can be used to identify words, like "deposit", "startdate", etc.

Comment: You have to make your own CRF